# Swift 'Cannot invoke with an argument list of type'

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to write a generic function which takes in any type conforming to a protocol, but that protocol has an `associatedtype` defined, and would like to constraint that `associatedtype`.

Here is what I have currently:

```
func load<GroceriesQuery: Query>(groceries: GroceriesQuery) where GroceriesQuery.Grocery == Vegetable { }
```

**UPDATE:** I created an example for just pasting in `Playground` which mimics the exact problem and setup I have in my project, just in a simpler way. The error message is also different in `Playgrounds`.

```
protocol Query {
    associatedtype Groceries
}

class CucumberQuery: Query {
    typealias Groceries = [Cucumber]
}

protocol Vegetable {
}

struct Cucumber: Vegetable {
}

func load<GroceriesQuery: Query>(groceries: GroceriesQuery) where GroceriesQuery.Groceries == [Vegetable] {
}

load(groceries: CucumberQuery())
```

However, when I try to call this function, I get the error:

> Cannot invoke 'load(groceries:)' with an argument list of type '(groceries: CucumberQuery)'

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the function (where the error occurs)?

Comment: Updated it with some examples.

Comment: Can you provide a full example someone could paste into a playground to get your error?

Comment: what is `Query`?

Comment: Please see my edits.

Comment: The error in your example is because you need to do `GroceriesQuery.Grocery: Vegetable` with the `:` instead of `==`

Comment: That makes sense, thanks @dan! How could I make it work for arrays? I edited the question. I can't use the `:` but the `==` still does not work.

Comment: I think you could do `where GroceriesQuery.Groceries: Sequence, GroceriesQuery.Groceries.Element: Vegetable`

Answer (score 1):

From the function declaration, it looks like the `associatedtype` on `Query` is called `Grocery` (see the `where` clause on your function). However, in your `class CucumberQuery` seems to only define a `Result`. You should change the class definition to:

```
class CucumberQuery: Query {
    typealias Grocery = Cucumber
}
```

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that part as I wrote the code from my phone.. could you check my edit?